# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole() Authorization issue

Tags: active-directory, authorization, httpcontext

I am facing a strange issue while authorizing myself via `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\RoleName")`.

There is an AD Group A which has another group B as a member. I am a member of A and B both. However when I try to authorize myself for A and B it gives me false and true respectively. That is for A it does not authorizes me while for B it does. Is it that even if I am member of parent group and child group, the IsInRole will authorize only for child group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my issue is resolved by one of the below ways:

1. I reset my IIS.
2. I deleted my cookies on the machine.

Miraculously, it worked. Thanks for your responses AviD.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not it - if you're looking for GroupA, and are a member of it, GroupB is irrelevant.
Could it be you misspelled it? Are they both in the same domain?
Otherwise verify that GroupA is a security group, otherwise it wont appear in your roles.

Comment: I have spelled it correctly. Yes, both are in same domain and same OU. Both are Security groups.

Comment: @Ashish, try removing GroupB from GroupA, to see if there's a difference - but I dont think there will be. There's probably something wrong with GroupA...

Comment: So can you just delete GroupA, and create a new one and put GroupB into that?

Comment: Hmm. I think that's the last option I can try.

Answer (score 0):

I did have a similar issue and after hours of debugging I solved it by logging off and logging with at the client after changing groups in the active directory.

I didn't have to restart the iis server or deleting all cookies.